# MySQL ignoring index for count query on INNODB table in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, hibernate, indexing, mysql-5.7

we've got one old database running MySQL 5.1. We now want to migrate it to MySQL 5.7 but some queries that worked okay are suddenly very very slow (by a factor of 60 or more slower).

The INNODB table in question (EVENT) has amongst other columns a COMPANY_ID (foreign key to a COMPANY table) and EVENT_DATETIME of type DATETIME. There is an index on COMPANY_ID, EVENT_DATETIME and for testing I've added one EVENT_DATETIME, COMPANY_ID.
Currently basically all EVENTs have the COMPANY_ID 1 but this will change.

We have a count query to query the number of events in the last year:

```
select count(distinct this_.EVENT_ID) as y0_ from EVENT this_
       where this_.EVENT_DATETIME>='2018-10-22 00:00:00'
         and this_.EVENT_DATETIME<='2019-11-21 00:00:00'
         and this_.COMPANY_ID = 1;
```

The result is around 1,000,000 rows and used to take about 1.5 seconds now it takes up to 100 seconds. While the query on MySQL 5.1 uses an index on COMPANY_ID and EVENT_DATETIME the index is ignored on MySQL 5.7. It seems if MySQL sees that it has to parse too many rows it gives up on an index even if it would help. If I reduce the window to e.g. 10 month MySQL 5.7 uses the index again.

So on MySQL 5.1 the index COMPANY_ID,EVENT_DATETIME is used
on MySQL it only uses a foreign key index for COMPANY_ID.

If I run the query without the where on the COMPANY_ID

```
select count(distinct this_.EVENT_ID) as y0_ from EVENT this_ 
       where this_.EVENT_DATETIME>='2018-10-22 00:00:00'
         and this_.EVENT_DATETIME<='2019-11-21 00:00:00';
```

the query is a lot faster.

Is there any way to force MySQL 5.7 to use a certain index?

If I rewrite the query to this:

```
select count(distinct this_.EVENT_ID) as y0_ from EVENT this_
     where this_.EVENT_DATETIME>='2018-10-22 00:00:00'
       and this_.EVENT_DATETIME<='2019-11-21 00:00:00'
     GROUP BY COMPANY_ID HAVING COMPANY_ID = 1;
```

it is back to about 1 to 1.5 seconds. The problem is we might have more than one of these queries and the queries are generated by Hibernate Criterias which do not support HAVING so my workaround won't work in real life.

Update: 
MySQL 5.7
Explain for 12 month query (1050757 rows in 40 seconds)

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "673838.60"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "this_",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
      "PRIMARY",
      "FK_EVENT_COMPANY",
      "IX_REFERENCE",
      "IX_DATE_TIME",
      "EVENT_DATETIME",
      "IDX_CE_COMPANY_TYPE",
      "IDX_CE_COMPANY_DATE",
      "IDX_CE_DATE_COMPANY"
      ],
      "key": "FK_EVENT_COMPANY",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "COMPANY_ID"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "ref": [
        "const"
      ],
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 2698153,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 1135826,
      "filtered": "42.10",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "134208.00",
        "eval_cost": "227165.40",
        "prefix_cost": "673838.60",
        "data_read_per_join": "1G"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "EVENT_ID",
        "COMPANY_ID",
        "EVENT_DATETIME"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`test`.`this_`.`EVENT_DATETIME` >= '2018-10-22 00:00:00') and (`test`.`this_`.`EVENT_DATETIME` <= '2019-11-21 00:00:00'))"
    }
  }
}
```

Explain for 10 month query

```
   {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "634047.16"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "this_",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "PRIMARY",
        "FK_EVENT_COMPANY",
        "IX_REFERENCE",
        "IX_DATE_TIME",
        "EVENT_DATETIME",
        "IDX_CE_COMPANY_TYPE",
        "IDX_CE_COMPANY_DATE",
        "IDX_CE_DATE_COMPANY"
      ],
      "key": "IDX_CE_DATE_COMPANY",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "EVENT_DATETIME"
      ],
      "key_length": "9",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 1578860,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 789430,
      "filtered": "50.00",
      "using_index": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "476161.16",
        "eval_cost": "157886.00",
        "prefix_cost": "634047.16",
        "data_read_per_join": "1G"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "EVENT_ID",
        "COMPANY_ID",
        "EVENT_DATETIME"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`test`.`this_`.`COMPANY_ID` = 1) and (`test`.`this_`.`EVENT_DATETIME` >= '2019-01-22 00:00:00') and (`test`.`this_`.`EVENT_DATETIME` <= '2019-11-21 00:00:00'))"
    }
  }
}
```

Interesting is that the first 12 month (slow) query does not show COMPANY_ID in the attached_condition while for the second 10 month query attached_condition has a check on COMPANY_ID.

ANALYZE TABLE as was suggested did not change anything it seems.

Update 2:
Explain for MySQL 5.1 (does not support JSON format) takes 1.3 sec

```
1    SIMPLE         this_  range   FK_EVENT_COMPANY,IX_DATE_TIME,EVENT_DATETIME,IDX_CE_COMPANY_TYPE,IDX_CE_COMPANY_DATE    IDX_CE_COMPANY_DATE 16      NULL    2018704   Using where; Using index
```

Comment: If you are using native sql, you use the index hint FORCE INDEX (Your Index name). But it looks like the query is generated by hibernate, not sure you can add index hint or not.

Comment: Run `explain` on both versions and post the result here. The explain will show the query plan and you will be able to compare them.

Comment: I meant the explain from MySQL 5.1 and 5.7.. So we can compare the decisions of the query planner for both versions

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead of trying to describe it in prose.

Comment: Which version of 5.7?

Answer (score 2):

The query planner may be taking wrong decisions based on the available statistics. You can try to run `ANALYZE` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html) to rebuild the stats and provide better numbers to the planner. Just notice that ANALYZE will block the table while it runs (it is fast).

**UPDATE**

Reading the MySQL documentation, I found this paragraph:

> Prior to MySQL 5.7.18, InnoDB processes `SELECT COUNT(*)` statements by scanning the clustered index. As of MySQL 5.7.18, InnoDB processes `SELECT COUNT(*)` statements by traversing the smallest available secondary index unless an index or optimizer hint directs the optimizer to use a different index. If a secondary index is not present, the clustered index is scanned.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

It meas that the count behavior changed exactly on the version you are using. It may explain the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried ANALYZE TABLE but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: And the 5.7.18 changelog:  "`SELECT COUNT(*)` performance regressed in some cases due to a modification introduced in MySQL 5.7.2 that caused InnoDB to count rows by traversing the clustered index instead of a smaller secondary index. The modification was reverted. (Bug #23046302, Bug #80580)"

Answer (score 0):

The optimal index is

```
INDEX(COMPANY_ID, EVENT_DATETIME, EVENT_ID)  -- in this order
```

I appears that your date range is 1 year + one day + 1 second.  Was that deliberate?

If `EVENT_ID` is the `PRIMARY KEY` (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`), then `COUNT(DISTINCT EVENT_ID)` could be simply `COUNT(*)`.